# Jquery print object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I pass from php to js object. For example :

```
{"3199":{"name":"Ramona RONDEREGGER","mail":"mona.schlaepfer@bluewin.ch","phone":null,"hope":null
 ,"status":"NEW LEAD"},"3253":{"name":"Olivia 
 BAUMANN","mail":"oliviazurfluh@gmail.com","phone":null,"hope"
 :null,"status":"NEW LEAD"}}
```

And I want to get data from  this object in js (get 3199, 3253 and their data (name,mail ...).
How can I do it? 
I try it:

```
 $(data).each(function(key,value){
     $(value).each(function(key,value){
         console.log(value);
     });
 });
```

But id doesn't work
Please, help me to solve this problem
Thanks

Comment: The string is actually being passed through to your JS, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through your object and get data by key. Here is the example of your dataset showed that how can you access the data in your result object.

```js
var data = {"3199":{"name":"Ramona RONDEREGGER","mail":"mona.schlaepfer@bluewin.ch","phone":null,"hope":null
 ,"status":"NEW LEAD"},

 "3253":{"name":"Olivia BAUMANN","mail":"oliviazurfluh@gmail.com","phone":null,"hope"
 :null,"status":"NEW LEAD"}};
 
 for(x in data){
 // this will print your key
 console.log("this is your key " + x);
 // this line will print your key object
 console.log(data[x]);
 //to access internal element
 console.log(data[x]['mail']);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify key like this `value["3199"]`

```js
var data = {"3199":{"name":"Ramona RONDEREGGER","mail":"mona.schlaepfer@bluewin.ch","phone":null,"hope":null,"status":"NEW LEAD"},"3253":{"name":"Olivia BAUMANN","mail":"oliviazurfluh@gmail.com","phone":null,"hope"
 :null,"status":"NEW LEAD"}};
 

 $(data).each(function(key,value){

                            $(value).each(function(key,value){
                                console.log(value["3199"]);
                            });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```